# Print matrix on the form [a b; c d; ... ]

Tags: matlab, printing, matrix

Is there a simple way to print a Matlab matrix in the same kind of format that is used for input, i.e. `[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`mat2str`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/mat2str.html):

```
>> A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
>> mat2str(A)
ans =
[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9]
```

To just display the matrix on screen:

```
disp(mat2str(A))
```

To specify how many digits of precision you want, use a second argument to `mat2str`:

```
disp(mat2str(A,7))
```